# Awk command with regex in it does not work properly

Tags: bash, awk, command

Well here is my folder structure

[image]

And here is my problem

[image]

I would like to know how is that possible that when the find command does research in `f_ignore2` .. the awk command is able to grep those files (file(b|c))  out of output which are located in the dir directory, but when the find command does research in f_ignore2/dir it does not work. It's weird and i don't know what to do .. do you have any idea guys ?

Comment: do you only need to skip fileb and file c?

Comment: no, instead of 'file(b|c)' could be every other regex, but still would like to know why it does not work in dir directory .. while in f_ignore2 or in hodnoceni it works fine

Comment: for loop condition is `k<=NF` not `k<=NR`.

Comment: Damn you're good, thank you so much

Comment: In future post text, not images, so we can test your script and any potential solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use this `awk` instead?

```
awk -F/ '!/\/file[bc]/'
```

print all lines except lines which has string `/fileb` or `/filec`.

Comment: No need for the parentheses or the `{print}` block: `awk -F/ '!/\/file[bc]/'` would be fine.